# Installation of Linux headers: generic vs non generic

Tags: 18.04, kernel, linux-headers

I was on kernel 4.18.20 and wanted to upgrade to 4.19. So, I visited the [ubuntu.kernel.com](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and found that 4.19.118 to be latest one. I can understand the low-latency kernel versions but I couldn't understand the generic and non-generic linux-headers. Below I am attaching a screenshot. A bit of explanation will be much appreciated.

[image: screenshot from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19.118/]

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  Both 4.18 and 4.19 are EOL in the Ubuntu amd64/i386 universe?  (security patches are not back-ported to those kernels; the last backport to 4.18 was mid-2019; 4.19 never went beyond *testing*)

Comment: I am using 18.04 LTS and post kernel 4.20 my laptop cannot detect the pch_cannonlake and WiFi sensors. I use to have occasional lags and battery backup is horrible. Although nvidia graphic card is detected but upon issuing the command `sensors-detect` for lm-sensors, my laptop reboots after sometime.

Comment: I would suggest using the non-HWE or GA kernel 4.15 which has all security patches of later kernels back-ported to it, rather than unsupported kernels you have to maintain yourself.  I wouldn't recommend un-patched/EOL kernels.

Comment: @guiverc Could you please confirm if this is the link regarding the kernel https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15.18/

Comment: The patched 4.15 kernel doesn't require the use of PPAs; it's found in normal sources and the `linux-generic` package. If you want the proposed (*testing* features) just enabled the -proposed repo (fixes are first tested via PPA, once they have a positive test they go to proposed)